# Objective-C openCV 2.4.6 iOS framework compiler trouble

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, armv7, i386

I have been successfully using OpenCV in a Universal Framework for both the simulator and a device.  Now I want to create an application and include OpenCV into my application.  Following are all the steps I have done.

1. Added the opencv2.framework to the project target (Link Binary With Libraries)
2. Added libc++.dylib to the project target (Link Binary With Libraries)
3. Added the to the Prefix.pch file (above the `#ifdef __OBJC__`

   ```
   #ifdef __cplusplus 
       #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
   #endif
   ```
4. In Build Settings, I set the Build Active Architecture Only to `NO`
5. In Build Settings, I set the Valid Architectures to `i386 armv7`
6. In Build Settings, I set the Other Linker Flags to `-ObjC -lstdc++`
7. In Build Settings, I checked my Search Paths (Framework Search Paths, Header Search Paths, and Library Search Paths) to be sure I am pointing to the location of the opencv2.framework and libidkit.a
8. I changed the .m to .mm in my appropriate Objective C++ file

If I select an iOS Simulator for the Destination, I receive Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
If I select an iOS Device for the Destination, I receive Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

In the Universal Framework there is an Aggregate Target that includes a script that builds for the simulator and the device.  I am wondering if I need to do something like that here.  Or if there is some other step I am missing.

Errors I get when the Simulator is the Destination:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /System/Library/innerID-iOS/libidkit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /System/Library/innerID-iOS/libidkit.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_IEngine_AddFingerprintFromFile", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand generateImageTemplates:] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_ClearDatabase", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand clearDB] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_Connect", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand createDB] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_GetDeltasAndCores", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand getDeltasAndCores:] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_GetFingerprintCount", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand verify] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_GetFingerprintImage", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand getFingerprintImage:] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_GetHardwareId", referenced from:
      _getHWID in idkit_helper.o
  "_IEngine_GetMinutiaeImage", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand getMinutiaeImage:] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_GetParameter", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand initializeEngine] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_GetUserCount", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand verify] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_InitUser", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand generateImageTemplates:] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_InitWithLicense", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand initializeEngine] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_MatchUser", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand verify] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_RegisterUser", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand generateImageTemplates:] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_SaveFingerprintImage", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand saveFingerprintImage:toFile:] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_SetLogFile", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand hasValidLicense] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_IEngine_SetParameter", referenced from:
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand hasValidLicense] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
      -[IDCaptureImageCommand initializeEngine] in IDCaptureImageCommand.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Errors I get when the Device is the Destination:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post part of the error message containing the missing symbols.

Comment: @Joe - Added the errors.  Also, just learned that libidkit.a is built only for the device, so ignore all of the __IEngine_... errors.

Comment: @Joe - Once I realized the problem was with __ALAssetsLibrary I ran a search and found that I needed to add the AssetsLibrary.framework